# Iterating over two pandas lists

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on cleaning up some of my code to make it a bit more pythonic, but I'm wondering if the below could be written in a nicer way with something like an itertools or pandas method. The below code works, however I'm hoping to remove the double for-loop and consolidate a bit of the code for performance reasons.

Ultimately, I'm working with a list of indices that call a Pandas column.

```
def foo(dataset):
  api_reshaped = pd.DataFrame(columns=['foo', 'bar'])
  k = 0

  for index, _ in dataset.iterrows():
    for key in dataset.iloc[index][0][0]:
      api_reshaped.loc[k, 'foo'] = key
      api_reshaped.loc[k, 'bar'] = dataset.iloc[index][0][0][key]
      k += 1
  return api_reshaped
```

Below is the expected input/output from this function:

```
 foo_input = pd.dataframe({
      'batch_data': [{'foo_query': [{'bar_query': 'data'}]}],
      'query_spell': ['foo']
    })

print foo_input(foo_input)
# expected_output = pd.dataframe({
#  'foo': 'foo_query',
#  'bar': [{'bar_query': 'data'}]
# })
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you show some data input and expected output?

Comment: Yes, of course. I just added some additional information on this. I believe I simplified it enough to drop the complexities but please let me know if any additional information will be helpful. Many thanks, Franco.

Comment: There are typos there could you validate the that code runs and it gives the expected input and output?

Comment: Yes, good catch. Believe I just fixed them all...

Comment: @sokeefe, Nope you haven't fixed them at all. Your function doesn't work with `foo_input`. In fact, you haven't tested your code at all, e.g. `pd.dataframe` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with transpose:

```
# your input data
foo_input = pd.DataFrame({
  'batch_data': [{'foo_query': [{'bar_query': 'data'}]}],
  'query_spell': ['foo']
})

# use list comprehension with transpose
df = pd.DataFrame([item for item in foo_input['batch_data']]).T.reset_index()

# rename your columns
df.columns = ['Foo', 'Bar']

      Foo              Bar
0   foo_query   [{'bar_query': 'data'}]
```

you can use `applymap` with a lambda function if you want to remove the list and just have a dict